# List of things users might be interested in

Tags: data-request

For a small project I'd love to have a list of tags which I can suggest my users for them to enter into their profile. Examples would be "food, photography, japan, typography, art, ...". Ideally those tags would also be hierarchical: food -> italian -> pizza

I somehow expect that such a list of tags exists, because it's not a very uncommon use case for users to be able to assign tags - but I can't find a comprehensive list anywhere which is publicly available.

Any hints where I might find one?

Comment: Are you familiar with ontologies? That might be a starting point.